# Posting content into the database with an image using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, controller, laravel-blade

I'm trying to post some stuff into the database using laravel, but It seems not to work...

This is what I get:

The HTML:

```
{{ Form::open(array('role' => 'form')) }}
                            <div class="form-body">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Titel</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Titel komt hier">
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Textarea</label>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" placeholder="Uw bericht..."></textarea>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="exampleInputFile1">Nieuws afbeelding</label>
                                    <input type="file" name="img">
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="form-actions">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn green" value="Oplsaan" />
                            </div>

                        {{ Form::close() }}

                        @if ($errors->any())
                            <ul>
                                {{ implode('', $errors->all('<li class="error">:message</li>')) }}
                            </ul>
                        @endif
```

That displays all well....

Exept when I try to 'post' the news, because that is what I try to do, it just refreses the page. The URL to that page is mydomain.com/admin/news/write

My router looks like this:

```
Route::resource('admin/news/write', 'AdminController@create');
```

First it was authenticated in a group:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
    {
            Route::resource('admin', 'AdminController');
            Route::resource('admin/news/write', 'AdminController@create');
    });
```

This all works, but when I change the Route::resource('admin/news/write', 'AdminController@create'); to Route::post('admin/news/write', 'AdminController@create'); I get an error, that I can't see...

Good, now my controller:

```
public function store()
{
    $rules = array(
        'title' => 'required',
        'message'   => 'required',
    );  

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->passes())
    {
        if (Input::only('title', 'message'))
        {

            return Redirect::to('admin/news/write')->with('message', 'Het nieuws werd gemaakt!');

        }

    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::to('admin/news/write')->with('message', "Er ging iets mis: ")->withErrors($validator);
    }

}
```

The problem is, I don't know how I can store an image to

> /public/pictures/news

And then store the full file name into the database, if someone could help me out... I need a response quick, beacause I have a deadline... :{

Kindest regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to tell your form using the laravel helper that this is going to be uploading a file...

```php
Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'role' => 'form', 'files' => true])
```

In your controller you want to get the file from the input

```php
$imgFile = Input::file('img');
```

Now to move the file from the temporary location it's been uploaded, to a more permanent location call the following (where $filename is what you want to call the uploaded file)...

```php
$dir = '../storage/app/upload/';
$imgFile->move($dir.$filename);
```

The path for the root of the app from here is ../ (one up from public) so..
../storage/app/upload/ would be a great location to use for uploaded files.

You can then just write:

```
$dir.$filename;
```

back to the database - job done :)

Edit :: -- Your Controller --

Your controller for parsing this is based on resources...

So your route will be:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::resource('admin', 'AdminController');
}
```

Your controller itself will have a structure such as (remembering this: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers):

```
class AdminController extends BaseController {
    public function index(){...}
    public function create(){...}
    public function 
    //The store() method is an action handled by the resource controller
    //Here we're using it to handle the post action from the current URL
    public function store()
    {
       $imgFile = Input::file('img');
       //processing code here....
    }
    public function show(){...}
    public function edit(){...}
    public function update(){...}
    public function destroy(){...}   
}
```

Comment: Well first to see your errors you'll want to go into, this depends on your laravel version, but either app/config/app.php for laravel 4 or config/app.php for laravel 5 and change the debug option to true.

This will prevent errors being suppressed - when accessing your controller.

Comment: As for resources always remember what each of the routes and methods are used for : http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#restful-resource-controllers  - so if create is being used as a GET request - then explicitly set your form to 'method' => 'GET'. 


If your sending a POST then use the store method in your controller for processing the incoming request. Hopefully turning debug on will help  with troubleshooting.

Comment: I'm using laravel 4 :p But My app debus is on true, The problem is, the page just refreshes, HOW do I need to build my controller? HOW will he look like?

Comment: I've edited my post which should hopefully point you in the right direction - especially with using restful resource controllers.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, but I'm also storing other data into the database, I'm trying to figer it out now by my self, I'll keep you guys updated.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue.

My controller:

```
    <?php
class AdminNewsController extends \BaseController {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return View::make('admin.news.create');
    }


    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return View::make('admin.news.create');
    }


    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store()
    {
        $rules = array(
            'title'         => 'required',
            'message'       => 'required',
            'publish'       => 'required'
            );
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

        //process the storage
        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            Session::flash('error_message', 'Fout:' . $validator->errors());
            return Redirect::to('admin/news/create')->withErrors($validator);
        }else{

            //store
            $news                   = new News;
            $news->title            = Input::get('title');
            $news->message          = Input::get('message');
            $news->img_url          = Input::file('img')->getClientOriginalName();
            $news->posted_by        = Auth::user()->username;
            $news->published_at     = time();
            $news->published        = Input::get('publish');
            $news->save();

            //save the image
            $destinationPath = 'public/pictures/news';

            if (Input::hasFile('img'))
{
    $file = Input::file('img');
    $file->move('public/pictures/news', $file->getClientOriginalName());
}
            //redirect
            Session::flash('success', 'Nieuws succesvol aangemaakt!');
            return Redirect::to('admin/news/create');

        }
    }


    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }


    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }


    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update($id)
    {
        //
    }


    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }


}
```

My create.blade.php

```
<div class="portlet-body form">
                    {{ Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'role' => 'form', 'files' => true]) }}
                            <div class="form-body">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Titel</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Titel komt hier">
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Textarea</label>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" placeholder="Uw bericht..."></textarea>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Nieuws afbeelding</label>
                                    {{ Form::file('img') }}
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Bericht publiceren?</label>
                                    <div class="radio-list">

                                        <label class="radio-inline">
                                        <span>
                                        {{ Form::radio('publish', '1') }}
                                        </span>
                                        <b style="color:green">Publiceren</b>
                                        </label>

                                        <label class="radio-inline">
                                        <span>
                                        {{ Form::radio('publish', '0', true) }}
                                        </span>
                                        <b style="color:red">Niet publiceren</b>
                                        </label>


                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="form-actions">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn green" value="Oplsaan" />
                            </div>

                        {{ Form::close() }}
                    </div>
```

Then It all work!

Thanks to Matt Barber for the help!